# Rendering transparent objects

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, alpha-transparency

I am trying to make a glass plane by adjusting the translucency of the object with alpha values. Currently, it is a black plane as my alpha values have no effect on my objects. Please have a look at the image:

[image: current state]

`glEnable(GL_BLEND);` **does nothing**

and

`glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);` **makes all my objects disappear**

> fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vTexCoord;

// uniform input data
struct LightProperties
{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct MaterialProperties
{
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
};

uniform LightProperties uLightingProperties;
uniform MaterialProperties uMaterialProperties;
uniform vec3 uViewPoint;

uniform sampler2D uTextureSampler;

// uniform input data
uniform float uAlpha;

// output data
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    // calculate vectors for lighting
    vec3 N = normalize(vNormal);
    vec3 L;

    // determine whether the light is a point light source or directional light
    if(uLightingProperties.position.w == 0.0f)
        L = normalize((uLightingProperties.position).xyz);
    else
        L = normalize((uLightingProperties.position).xyz - vPosition);

    vec3 V = normalize(uViewPoint - vPosition);
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

    vec3 colour = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // calculate Phong lighting
    vec4 ambient = uLightingProperties.ambient * uMaterialProperties.ambient;
    vec4 diffuse = uLightingProperties.diffuse * uMaterialProperties.diffuse * max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 specular = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    if(dot(L, N) > 0.0f)
    {
        specular = uLightingProperties.specular * uMaterialProperties.specular 
            * pow(max(dot(V, R), 0.0), uLightingProperties.shininess);
    }

    // set output color
    colour = (diffuse + specular + ambient).rgb;    
    colour *= texture(uTextureSampler, vTexCoord).rgb;
    fColor = vec4(colour, uAlpha);
    //fColor = texture(uTextureSampler, vTexCoord).rgb;
}
```

This gives me an opaque black plane when what I want is a translucent black plane.

```
static void init(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    //glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
    //glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);

    // read image data
    g_texImage[0] = readBitmapRGBImage("images/check.bmp", &imageWidth[0], &imageHeight[0]);
    g_texImage[1] = readBitmapRGBImage("images/smile.bmp", &imageWidth[1], &imageHeight[1]);
    g_texImage[2] = readBitmapRGBImage("images/Fieldstone.bmp", &imageWidth[2], &imageHeight[2]);
    g_texImage[3] = readBitmapRGBImage("images/sunflower.bmp", &imageWidth[3], &imageHeight[3]);
    g_texImage[4] = readBitmapRGBImage("images/painting.bmp", &imageWidth[4], &imageHeight[4]);

    // create and compile GLSL program from the shader files
    g_shaderProgramID[0] = loadShaders("vertex_shaderL.vert", "fragment_shaderL.frag");
    g_shaderProgramID[1] = loadShaders("vertex_shaderT.vert", "fragment_shaderT.frag");

    // find the locations of shader variables
    GLuint positionIndex[2];
    positionIndex[0] = glGetAttribLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "aPosition");
    GLuint normalIndex = glGetAttribLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "aNormal");
    GLuint texCoordIndex = glGetAttribLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "aTexCoord");

    g_MVP_Index = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uModelViewProjectionMatrix");
    g_M_Index = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uModelMatrix");
    g_viewPointIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uViewPoint");
    g_alphaIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uAlpha");

    g_texSampler_Index[0] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uTextureSampler");

    g_lightPositionIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uLightingProperties.position");
    g_lightAmbientIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uLightingProperties.ambient");
    g_lightDiffuseIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uLightingProperties.diffuse");
    g_lightSpecularIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uLightingProperties.specular");
    g_lightShininessIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uLightingProperties.shininess");

    g_materialAmbientIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uMaterialProperties.ambient");
    g_materialDiffuseIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uMaterialProperties.diffuse");
    g_materialSpecularIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[0], "uMaterialProperties.specular");

    positionIndex[1] = glGetAttribLocation(g_shaderProgramID[1], "aPosition");
    g_texSampler_Index[1] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[1], "uTextureSampler");
    g_renderDepth_Index = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID[1], "uRenderDepth");

    // initialise model matrices
    g_mm_floor = translate(vec3(0.2f, -4.0f, 0.0f));
    g_mm_cube = translate(vec3(0.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f)) * scale(vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        g_mm_wall[i] = mat4(1.0f);
    }
    g_mm_painting[0] = mat4(1.0f);
    g_mm_painting[1] = mat4(1.0f);
    g_mm_glass = mat4(1.0f);
    g_mm_torus = mat4(1.0f);

    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    float aspectRatio = static_cast<float>(width) / height;

    // camera
    g_camera.setViewMatrix(vec3(0, 1, 10), vec3(0, 0, -10), vec3(0, 1, 0));
    g_camera.setProjectionMatrix(perspective(45.0f, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 100.0f));

    // initialise light and material properties
    g_lightProperties.position = vec4(7.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.ambient = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.diffuse = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.specular = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.shininess = 10.0f;

    g_materialProperties[0].ambient = vec4(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    g_materialProperties[0].diffuse = vec4(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
    g_materialProperties[0].specular = vec4(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    g_materialProperties[1].ambient = vec4(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    g_materialProperties[1].diffuse = vec4(0.2f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    g_materialProperties[1].specular = vec4(0.2f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    g_materialProperties[2].ambient = vec4(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    g_materialProperties[2].diffuse = vec4(0.2f, 0.7f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    g_materialProperties[2].specular = vec4(0.2f, 0.7f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

    // generate identifier for texture object and set texture properties
    // checkered floor
    glGenTextures(10, g_textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, imageWidth[0], imageHeight[0], 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texImage[0]);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // smiley face
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, imageWidth[1], imageHeight[1], 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texImage[1]);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // fieldstone wallpaper
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[2]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, imageWidth[2], imageHeight[2], 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texImage[2]);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // sunflower painting
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[3]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, imageWidth[3], imageHeight[3], 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texImage[3]);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // other painting
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[4]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, imageWidth[4], imageHeight[4], 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texImage[4]);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // textures to be rendered to (i.e. render-to-texture)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[6]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, g_windowWidth, g_windowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[7]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, g_windowWidth, g_windowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // set up framebuffer object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &g_FBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_FBO);

    GLuint depthRenderBufferID;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderBufferID);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, g_windowWidth, g_windowHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID);

    // associate respective textures with framebuffer attachments
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, g_textureID[6], 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, g_textureID[7], 0);

    // number of draw buffers
    GLenum drawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
    glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // generate identifier for VBOs and copy data to GPU
    glGenBuffers(10, g_VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(10, g_VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertices), g_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex[0], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, position)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, normal)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, texCoord)));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalIndex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordIndex);

    // to display the render-to-texture's texture on a screen space quad
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_screenspaceQuad), g_screenspaceQuad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex[1], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex[1]);

    // torus mesh
    load_mesh("models/torus.obj", 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*g_numberOfVertices[0], g_pMeshVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[3]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint) * 3 * g_numberOfFaces[0], g_pMeshIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[2]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[2]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[3]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex[0], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, position)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, normal)));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalIndex);
}

static void render_scene()
{
    // draw to frame buffer object
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_FBO);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(g_shaderProgramID[0]);

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);

    // set lighting properties
    glUniform4fv(g_lightPositionIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.position[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_lightAmbientIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_lightDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_lightSpecularIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.specular[0]);
    glUniform1fv(g_lightShininessIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.shininess);

    // set uniform shader variables
    mat4 MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_glass;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_glass[0][0]);
    glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 0.5);

    // set material properties
    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].specular[0]);

    // draw glass
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // set uniform shader variables
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_cube;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_cube[0][0]);
    glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 1.0);

    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].specular[0]);

    // draw cube
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[1]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, 36);

    // set uniform shader variables
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_floor;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_floor[0][0]);
    glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 1.0);

    // set material properties
    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].specular[0]);

    // draw floor
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // set uniform shader variables
        MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_wall[i];
        glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_wall[i][0][0]);
        glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 1.0);

        // set material properties
        glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[1].ambient[0]);
        glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[1].diffuse[0]);
        glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[1].specular[0]);

        // draw walls
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[2]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    // set uniform shader variables
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_painting[0];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_painting[0][0][0]);
    glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 1.0);

    // set material properties
    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].specular[0]);

    // draw apples painting
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[3]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // set uniform shader variables
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_painting[1];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_painting[1][0][0]);
    glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 1.0);

    // set material properties
    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[2].specular[0]);

    // draw other painting
    if (newpainting == false)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[4]);
    else
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[5]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // set uniform shader variables
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[2]);
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_mm_torus;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_MVP_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_M_Index, 1, GL_FALSE, &g_mm_torus[0][0]);
    glUniform1f(g_alphaIndex, 1.0);

    // set material properties
    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties[0].specular[0]);

    // draw torus
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, g_numberOfFaces[0] * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // draw to normal display
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(g_shaderProgramID[1]);

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[1]);

    glUniform1i(g_texSampler_Index[1], 0);

    // draw screenspace quad
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    if (g_bRenderDepth)
    {
        glUniform1i(g_renderDepth_Index, 1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[7]);
    }
    else
    {
        glUniform1i(g_renderDepth_Index, 0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID[6]);
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: To add to Rabbid76 comment: In case of transparent objects, drawing order matters. Could it be that you are rendering the transparent object before the opaque ones?

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, I updated with my init and render functions, hopefully that makes the picture clearer.

Comment: Hi @BDL, I updated with my init and render functions, hopefully that makes the picture clearer.

Comment: this is way too much code for a so  question... do you have any gl errors?
did you try outputing a=.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When rendering transparent objects, it is important to render everything in the correct order. That is:

1. Render all opaque objects
2. Render all transparent objects (if there are multiple, then you'll have to sort them back to front.

Currently, you are rendering the glass object first, which sets the depth values in the depth buffer. All objects behind the glass will never be draw because they fail the z-test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried moving the render plane code to the back (after the opaque objects), and it took on the texture of the object before it. And still when I call glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);, everything still disappears.

Comment: Why do you use different blending equations for the alpha channel? That doesn't make sense in this scenario. Although I'm not sure if it really makes a difference.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't realise glEnable(GL_BLEND) would suffice. Currently, I'm only calling glEnable(GL_BLEND) and the plane has taken on the texture of the painting (when moved to the back). Is translucency not supposed to be obvious on textured objects? I changed the float to 0.1 and there wasn't a visible difference.